# requests is giving error 'certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

When I run my program that uses the requests module to send info to an api, I get the error:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.fast2sms.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /dev/bulkV2?authorization=vQWJE07LzxhrR8TM1lDBUK6gASOPy4miVnkf3bHXGZNs9YcI2o3GScblwJY7kmx1rpDWuBnLhVH54vKC&sender_id=TXTIND&route=v3&language=unicode&numbers=14372341004&message=FastSMS+test%0A (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')))
```

I've gotten this error before when using requests, I just never tried to fix it.

Full error code:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 386, in _make_request        
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1040, in _validate_conn      
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 414, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 449, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 493, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl     
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 512, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 1070, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 1341, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)  

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 440, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 785, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 592, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.fast2sms.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /dev/bulkV2?authorization=vQWJE07LzxhrR8TM1lDBUK6gASOPy4miVnkf3bHXGZNs9YcI2o3GScblwJY7kmx1rpDWuBnLhVH54vKC&sender_id=TXTIND&route=v3&language=unicode&numbers=14372341004&message=FastSMS+test%0A (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\Temp1_Pythonista_ForAll-main.zip\Pythonista_ForAll-main\SMS_Sender\SMSAutomation.py", line 25, in btn_clk
    r = send_sms(num,msg)
  File "c:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\Temp1_Pythonista_ForAll-main.zip\Pythonista_ForAll-main\SMS_Sender\SMSAutomation.py", line 17, in send_sms
    response = requests.get(url, params=prams)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 529, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 645, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 517, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.fast2sms.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /dev/bulkV2?authorization=vQWJE07LzxhrR8TM1lDBUK6gASOPy4miVnkf3bHXGZNs9YcI2o3GScblwJY7kmx1rpDWuBnLhVH54vKC&sender_id=TXTIND&route=v3&language=unicode&numbers=14372341004&message=FastSMS+test%0A (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')))
```

Comment: Maybe try updating your certificates with `python -m pip install --upgrade certifi`?

Comment: @C.Nivs it says requirement already satisfied.